# How to add auto complete to a text form field?

Tags: autocomplete, dart, flutter, text-formatting

I tried using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/autocomplete_textfield but can't use it in a text form field.

If possible, I would also like to add focus to this field when needed.

Comment: You can't use AutoCompleteTextField in text form field.

Comment: Any work around?

Comment: If you want to use AutoCompleteTextField in text form field then there is no way. Try to do it programmatically.

Comment: Okay! Will do, Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [flutter_typeahead](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_typeahead) plugin and it gives all the options as in a text form field including autofocus.

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin :
[enter link description here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_typeahead)

you can even customize it by checking the source code